# "fatal error: stdio.h : No such file or directory" while compiling a C file

Tags: compiling, c

Trying to compile following code in terminal i got

```
root@debian:/home/mz2/Documentos# LANG=C ./soma.c 
./soma.c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./soma.c: line 2: `int soma (int a, int b);'
```

The file soma.c is

```
#include < stdio.h >
int soma (int a, int b);
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
     int x, y, z;
     x = 10;
     y = 12;
     z = soma(x, y);
     fprintf(stdout, "A soma de %d com %d é %d\n", x, y, z);
     return 0;
  }
  int soma (int a, int b) {
  return (a + b);
  }
```

When I run

```
  root@debian:/home/mz2/Documentos# LANG=C gcc -o soma soma.c
  soma.c:1:21: fatal error:  stdio.h : No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
```

And...

```
  root@debian:/home/mz2/Documentos# LANG=C gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o    soma soma.c
  soma.c:1:21: fatal error:  stdio.h : No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
```

How can I fix this and run it?

Comment: Your title didn't match your question: you didn't even try to run gcc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to compile it; as in:

```
gcc -o soma soma.c
```

Then run by:

```
./soma
```

As of now you are running is as a script with what ever shell you are using.

A better compile line would be:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o soma soma.c
```

That line will give you a lot of help and hints. And always remember to compile often so you do not have to fix walls of errors at the same time.

To enhance the user experience you can also try out `colorgcc` (if available). A wrapper for gcc that outputs colorized warnings, errors etc.

Also available [here](https://github.com/colorgcc/colorgcc) by http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html

---

You also have an error in your code as you have spaces around `<` and `>` in include:

```
#include < stdio.h >
```

Should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this command didn't fix it.... Please see above

Comment: @VitorMazuco: See update.

Comment: @VitorMazuco: Also note that you should use a proper editor. Most have some way to add extra help for you in the editor (giving you errors and warnings in editor - so you do not have to even try to compile.) Example: Sytastic for vim: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736 - If you use another editor try to find out if it has plugins or similar to help out.

Comment: @VitorMazuco: Also not that there is no need for `LANG=C` on your compile line ... I also suspect you have done `chmod +x soma.c` as you are able to execute it. That is nor needed (or desirable).

Comment: Also make sure lib6-dev is installed: `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev`